# PySpark, Decision Trees (Spark 2.0.0)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, decision-tree

I am new to Spark (using PySpark). I tried running the Decision Tree tutorial from [here (link)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-decision-tree.html). I execute the code:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

# Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt").toDF()
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)

# Now this line fails
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)
```

I get the error message:

> IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.'

When searching the web for this error I found an answer that says:

> use
> `from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT`
> instead of
> `from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT`

which is odd, since I haven't used it. Also, adding this import to my code solves nothing and I still get the same error.

I am not quite clear on how to debug this situation. When looking into the raw data I see:

```
data.show()
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|(692,[127,128,129...|  0.0|
|(692,[158,159,160...|  1.0|
|(692,[124,125,126...|  1.0|
|(692,[152,153,154...|  1.0|
```

This looks like a list, starts with '('.

I am not sure how to solve this issue, or even debug.

Comment: which version spark are you using?

Comment: I am using Spark 2.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the problem seems to be executing spark 1.5.2. example on spark 2.0.0 (see below reference to spark 2.0 example).

**The difference between spark.ml and spark.mllib**

*As of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the spark.mllib package have entered maintenance mode. The primary Machine Learning API for Spark is now the DataFrame-based API in the spark.ml package.*

More details can be found here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

Using spark 2.0 please try **Spark 2.0.0 example** (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/mllib-decision-tree.html)

```
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree, DecisionTreeModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

# Load and parse the data file into an RDD of LabeledPoint.
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a DecisionTree model.
#  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                     impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)

# Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
predictions = model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))
labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(testData.count())
print('Test Error = ' + str(testErr))
print('Learned classification tree model:')
print(model.toDebugString())

# Save and load model
model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
sameModel = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
```

Find full example code at "examples/src/main/python/mllib/decision_tree_classification_example.py" in the Spark repo.

Comment: feel a bit silly. I just didn't pay attention to the version. Thanks!